# If the heat transfer in a particular direction is negligible then is it necessary that the temperature variation will also be negligible?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, thermal-conductivity

Imagine having a rectangular block. If the heat transfer is predominant in only one direction (say x) and the heat transfer in the other two directions (say y and z) is negligible, then can I conclude, always, the temperature variation in the y and z directions will be very small?

Comment: Yes, as long as the material is isotropic.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank You very much.

Answer (score 0):

> If the heat transfer in a particular direction is negligible then is
> it necessary that the temperature variation will also be negligible?

Yes, assuming isotropic material behavior (thermal conductivity the same in all directions).

It follows from Fourier's Law of Heat Conduction that

$$\vec q=-k\nabla T$$

Where

$\vec q$ = heat flux (W/m$^2$)

$k$ = thermal conductivity (W/(m.K)

$\nabla T$ = temperature gradient (K/m)

Then, for an isotropic material

$$\vec q=-k\biggl(\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}\vec i+\frac{\partial T}{\partial y}\vec j+\frac{\partial T}{\partial z}\vec k\biggr )$$

From which it follows that if the heat flux is in the x direction only, then the temperature variation (gradient) in the y and z direction is zero.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You implicitly assume that the thermal conductivity is isotropic.

Comment: I think I explicitly assumed that

Comment: My bad. Same comment without 'implicitly'. So both answers are correct.

Answer (score 0):

> If the heat transfer in a particular direction is negligible then is it necessary that the temperature variation will also be negligible?

No.

Heat transfer is mediated by both the temperature gradient *and* the geometry and material properties, which can vary with direction. If heat transfer in a particular direction is negligible, then either the temperature gradient is very small, or the thermal conductivity in that direction is very small, or both, but I cannot exclude the latter possibility (unless you also guarantee that the thermal properties of the block are isotropic, for example). This is an important aspect of modeling laminates, for instance.